# STM32 and NRF send & receive

Tags: spi, nrf24l01+

This is my send and receive code in STM32 (blue board).
But i can't send and receive data . why?
I did use Enrf24.h .
Enrf24 link: https://github.com/spirilis/Enrf24
send code is:

```
#include <SPI.h>
#include <Enrf24.h>
#include <nRF24L01.h>
#include <string.h>
#define ce_nrf PB12
#define csn_nrf PB13
#define irq_nrf PA0
Enrf24 radio(ce_nrf, csn_nrf, irq_nrf);  // P2.0=CE, P2.1=CSN, P2.2=IRQ
const uint8_t txaddr[] = { 0xDE, 0xAD, 0xBE, 0xEF, 0x01 };
void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  SPI.begin();
  SPI.setDataMode(SPI_MODE0);
  SPI.setBitOrder(MSBFIRST);
  radio.begin();  // Defaults 1Mbps, channel 0, max TX power
  radio.setTXaddress((void*)txaddr);
}

void loop() {
  Serial.print("Sending packet: ");
  radio.print("OONN");
  radio.flush();  // Force transmit (don't wait for any more data)
  delay(1000);
  Serial.print("Sending packet: ");
  radio.print("OOFF");
  radio.flush();
  delay(1000);
}
```

receive code is:

```
#include <SPI.h>
#include <Enrf24.h>
#include <nRF24L01.h>
#define ce_nrf PB12
#define csn_nrf PB13
#define irq_nrf PA0
Enrf24 radio(ce_nrf, csn_nrf, irq_nrf);  // P2.0=CE, P2.1=CSN, P2.2=IRQ
const uint8_t rxaddr[] = { 0xDE, 0xAD, 0xBE, 0xEF, 0x01 };
const char *str_on = "ON";
const char *str_off = "OFF";
void dump_radio_status_to_serialport(uint8_t);
void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  SPI.begin();
  SPI.setDataMode(SPI_MODE0);
  SPI.setBitOrder(MSBFIRST);
  radio.begin();  // Defaults 1Mbps, channel 0, max TX power
  radio.setRXaddress((void*)rxaddr);
  radio.enableRX();  // Start listening
}

void loop() {
  char inbuf[33];
  while (!radio.available(true));
  if (radio.read(inbuf)) {
    Serial.print("Received packet: ");
    Serial.println(inbuf);
  }
}
```

this image can help :
[image]

Comment: And the question is?

Comment: Thanks, i can't send and receive data . why? please see my image

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You did not say which library you are using, but based on the `#include`s, I am assuming http://maniacbug.github.io/RF24

This line in your receiver code:

```
  while (!radio.available(true));
```

does not make sense. You are passing `true` to the `radio.available()` function, but t[he function does not care about a parameter](http://maniacbug.github.io/RF24/classRF24.html#a127105eb7a3b351cfe777c1cec50627a).

You probably mean something like:

```
while (!radio.available());
```

When you pass in a variable, you are calling a variant of the function that expects a pipe number to be given, and `true` is defined as `1`. Your transmitter, however, is not sending on pipe number 1.

Comment: I use this library   [link](https://github.com/spirilis/Enrf24)  . in exmaple folder you can see some example  i did use Enrf24

Answer (score 0):

First of all, remove

```
while (!radio.available(true));
```

after that use

```
PA_5 ----> SCK
PA_6 ----> MISO
PA_7 ----> MOSI
```

it will work correctly.

Answer (score -1):

It is better answer for some reseans
in Enrf library you can not send data with write untill txbuf_len==0

> size_t Enrf24::write(uint8_t c) {
>   if (txbuf_len == 32) {
>   flush();  // Blocking OTA TX   }
>   txbuf[txbuf_len] = c;   txbuf_len++;
>   return 1; }

dont use purge then

> txbuf_len = 0

this is for read dat

```
#include <SPI.h>
#include <Enrf24.h>
#include <nRF24L01.h>
#define ce_nrf PB12
#define csn_nrf PB13
#define irq_nrf PA0
Enrf24 radio(ce_nrf, csn_nrf, irq_nrf);  // P2.0=CE, P2.1=CSN, P2.2=IRQ
const uint8_t rxaddr[] = { 0xDE, 0xAD, 0xBE, 0xEF, 0x01 };
const char *str_on = "ON";
const char *str_off = "OFF";
void dump_radio_status_to_serialport(uint8_t);
void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  SPI.begin();
  SPI.setDataMode(SPI_MODE0);
  SPI.setBitOrder(MSBFIRST);
  radio.begin();  // Defaults 1Mbps, channel 0, max TX power
  radio.setRXaddress((void*)rxaddr);
  radio.enableRX();  // Start listening
 // radio.autoAck(false);
}

void loop() {
  char inbuf[35];
  if (radio.read(inbuf))
  {
    Serial.print("Received packet: ");
    Serial.println(inbuf);
  } 
}
```

this is write for write data:

```
#include <SPI.h>
#include <Enrf24.h>
#include <nRF24L01.h>
#include <string.h>
#define ce_nrf PB12
#define csn_nrf PB13
#define irq_nrf PA0
Enrf24 radio(ce_nrf, csn_nrf, irq_nrf);  // P2.0=CE, P2.1=CSN, P2.2=IRQ
const uint8_t txaddr[] = { 0xDE, 0xAD, 0xBE, 0xEF, 0x01 };
void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  SPI.begin();
  SPI.setDataMode(SPI_MODE0);
  SPI.setBitOrder(MSBFIRST);
  radio.begin();  // Defaults 1Mbps, channel 0, max TX power
  radio.setTXaddress((void*)txaddr);
}
int i=0;
void loop() {
  i++;
  Serial.print("Sending packet: ");
  Serial.println(i);
  radio.print("1234567890123456789012--------->");
  //radio.purge();
  delay(100);
}
```

Comment: what is in principle the difference between the code in question an code in answer? only the removed while (available)?